# Prevent changes in resources while calculations are in progress

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, locking, task-parallel-library

I have an application that works quite slow and I'm trying to speed it up.
I am quite new to concurrent systems, so I'm a bit stuck here.

Shortly, I can present the system as the following classes:

Some resource that is being processed

```
public class Resource
{
    public int Capacity { get; set; } = 1000;
}
```

A consumer

```
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly int _sleep;

    public Consumer(int sleep)
    {
        _sleep = sleep;
    }

    public void ConsumeResource(Resource resource)
    {
        var capture = resource.Capacity;
        Thread.Sleep(_sleep);   // some calsulations and stuff
        if (resource.Capacity != capture)
            throw new SystemException("Something went wrong");
        resource.Capacity -= 1;
    }
}
```

And resource manager that does the job

```
public class ResourceManager
{
    private readonly List<Consumer> _consumers;
    private readonly Resource _resource;

    public ResourceManager(List<Consumer> consumers)
    {
        _consumers = consumers;
        _resource = new Resource();
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        Parallel.For(0, _consumers.Count, i =>
        {
            var consumer = _consumers[i];
            consumer.ConsumeResource(_resource);
        });
    }
}
```

So as you saw, Consumer relies on Resource state. If you run this simulation with the following code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var consumers = new List<Consumer>
    {
        new Consumer(1000),
        new Consumer(900),
        new Consumer(800),
        new Consumer(700),
        new Consumer(600),
    };

    var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(consumers);
    resourceManager.Process();
}
```

you will see that when capacity of resource changes, everything breaks.

I couldn't think of any other example, and it lacks a couple of details.

- First, there are many instances of Resource class, so locking access
  to it would not discard all efforts to make the code concurrent.
- Second, in real application this problem is very rare, so I can
  sacrifice a bit of performance there.

I'm guessing this issue can be fixed with properly placed `lock`s, but I fail to place them correctly.

As I understand the concept of `lock`s, it prevents the locked code from being called from different threads simultaneously. Placing `lock` in `Consumer::ConsumeResource` would not help, just as placing it inside `Resource::Capacity` setter. I need somehow to lock modification of a resource while a consumer is doing it's job with the resource.

I hope I explained my problem efficiently. It is all quite new to me, so I'll try to make things more concrete if needed.

---

After thinking long and hard, I conjured a somewhat sloppy solution.

I decided to lock Resource property for a consumer using comsumer's id, and manually wait for next consumer's turn:

```
public class Resource
{
    private int Capacity { get; set; } = 1000;

    private Guid? _currentConsumer;

    public int GetCapacity(Guid? id)
    {
        while (id.HasValue && _currentConsumer.HasValue && id != _currentConsumer)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }

        _currentConsumer = id;
        return Capacity;
    }

    public void SetCapacity(int cap, Guid id)
    {
        if (_currentConsumer.HasValue && id != _currentConsumer)
            return;

        Capacity = cap;
        _currentConsumer = null;
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    private readonly int _sleep;

    private Guid _id = Guid.NewGuid();

    public Consumer(int sleep)
    {
        _sleep = sleep;
    }

    public void ConsumeResource(Resource resource)
    {
        var capture = resource.GetCapacity(_id);
        Thread.Sleep(_sleep);   // some calsulations and stuff
        if (resource.GetCapacity(_id) != capture)
            throw new SystemException("Something went wrong");
        resource.SetCapacity(resource.GetCapacity(_id) - 1, _id);
    }
}
```

This way it works as expected, but I get a feeling that it also can be implemented with `lock`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research about `lock`s and stuff, I wrote that little helper class:

```
public class ConcurrentAccessProvider<TObject>
{
    private readonly Func<TObject> _getter;
    private readonly Action<TObject> _setter;
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public ConcurrentAccessProvider(Func<TObject> getter, Action<TObject> setter)
    {
        _getter = getter;
        _setter = setter;
    }

    public TObject Get()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return _getter();
        }
    }

    public void Set(TObject value)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _setter(value);
        }
    }

    public void Access(Action accessAction)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            accessAction();
        }
    }
}
```

With that, I rewrote `Resource` and `Consumer` in order to make it thread-safe:

```
public class Resource
{
    public ConcurrentAccessProvider<int> CapacityAccessProvider { get; }
    private int _capacity;

    public Resource()
    {
        CapacityAccessProvider = new ConcurrentAccessProvider<int>(() => _capacity, val => _capacity = val);
    }

    public int Capacity
    {
        get => CapacityAccessProvider.Get();
        set => CapacityAccessProvider.Set(value);
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    private readonly int _sleep;

    public Consumer(int sleep)
    {
        _sleep = sleep;
    }

    public void ConsumeResource(Resource resource)
    {
        resource.CapacityAccessProvider.Access(() =>
        {
            var capture = resource.Capacity;
            Thread.Sleep(_sleep);   // some calsulations and stuff
            if (resource.Capacity != capture)
                throw new SystemException("Something went wrong");
            resource.Capacity -= 1;

            Console.WriteLine(resource.Capacity);
        });
    }
}
```

In the provided example those manipulations effectively kill all possible profits from concurrency, but it is because there is only one `Resource` instance. In real world application when there are thousands of resources and only several conflicting cases, that will work just fine.